# system + usleep + multi-thread = SEGV / SIGILL

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am using kernel version 2.6.10 and "plain" C.

I have narrowed-down to two threads on why our program crashes.

**TIMER THREAD**

```
void TimerThread(void)
{
    while (exec) {
        usleep(10000);

        RSLTCD r = SUCCESS;
        // r = LockMutex(Mtx);
        do {
              // some process
        } while(1);     
        // r = UnlockMutex(Mtx);
    }
    return ;        // Not Reached
}
```

**SYSTEM THREAD**

```
void SystemThread(void)
{
    CreateThread(TimerThread, OALTHRD_DEFAULT_STACKSIZE, THREADPRI_NORMAL, 0, 0);
    for(;;){
        system("echo this is a SYSTEM CALL 1");
        system("echo this is a SYSTEM CALL 2");
    }    
}
```

I have remove all the rest of the code and even with just running this two "simple" threads,
the program will crash after a few loops(50-100).
I have also read that system() uses fork() and there are sometimes trouble with fork()ing and mutexes.
So I removed the mutex part and still it crashes.

I tried making my own "system call" function using fork()+execv() combo and also posix_spawn().
Both cases resulted with the same result.

Also, I have tried using other sleep functions than usleep.(nano_sleep, etc)
Still the programs crashes

Is there trouble with using system() and usleep() in multi-thread processes? What other alternatives do I have other than using these functions?

Comment: Could you get backtrace from when it crashes (and add it to the question)?

Comment: I have tried getting the backtrace() on the signal handler, but nothing comes out of it. I tried messing with the configuration of compiler but it doesnt seem to produce any symbols.

Comment: It's unspecified how `usleep` works, whether it uses signals, or whether (or how) it interacts with a number of other syscalls. So, long story short, just don't use it. There's `nanosleep` which was designed not to have any such issues. My guess is that once every while, your signal goes into the wrong process after `fork`. That's assuming your mutex functions (which aren't shown) are not broken, of course.

Comment: @NazeKimi: `backtrace()` is pretty worthless; you need to use debugger. I presume you can't run debugger on the target, but it would be enough to enable core-dump and feed the binary and the core dump to gdb on your development machine (it still needs to be compiled to understand the target architecture though). Or get the remote debugging stub working.

Comment: @Naze Kimi , have you ever solved this ?

Comment: @hudac, i have stopped using the "system()" function on my main multi-threaded application. What I did was run another single thread application that will run the system calls. The main application now sends messages to this "system call server". And the server just sends back the return value. Now can just choose any inter-process communication(pipes, semaphore, shared-memory, sockets) that you're comfortable with. I used UDP socket with our program.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is not easy to mix multi-threading and "fork()" and a lot more details about your SW would be needed to provide useful help. Please read http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them for description of the problems when mixing threads and fork().

Comment: I have read that link a lot of times. That's where I found about mutexes and fork(). But as you can see even removing those mutexes and retaining only ulseep(). It still crashes. I have even removed everything on the do-while block.

Comment: What are other threads doing, do they call any libc functions? "system" at least messes up with signals and uses "wait". Could you try to replace "system" with "fork/exec/wait" bunch? Will take more code, but will reduce the number of possible failure points.

Comment: The code I posted is ALL of it. I am only now running and debugging only those two threads, with the System thread as the "main thread". I have removed all other code to pinpoint where it goes wrong. I have also tried fork/exec/wait, which resulted with the same error.